# Why my cookie appear in my Network but not in my Application ? NestJS backend server

Tags: cookies, server, nestjs, backend, response

I am implementing a NestJS Backend server for my application. I would like to generate cookie in my response when a user signup or login.
I am able to get my cookie when signing up but when i log out and then signin, i well see my token generated in my network but no cookie in my application.

Here is my auth.controller file:

```
    async signup(@Req() req, @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: ExpressResponse) { 
        return (await this.authService.signup(req, res));
    }

    @Post('login')
    async login(@Req() req, @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: ExpressResponse) {
        return (await this.authService.login(req, res));
    }

    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    @Get('signout')
    async signout(@Req() req, @Res() res: ExpressResponse) { 
        console.log({"SIGNOUT REQUEST": req})
        try {   
            res.clearCookie('token');
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Logout successful' });
    
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        }
    }
```

And here are my services :

```
   async signup(@Req() req, @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: ExpressResponse) {
        const hash = await argon.hash(req.body.password);
        try {
            const user = await this.prisma.user.create({
                data: {
                    email: req.body.email,
                    username: req.body.username,
                    first_name: req.body.first_name,
                    last_name: req.body.last_name,
                    hash,
                },
            });
            const accessToken = await this.signToken(user.id, user.email);
            await this.prisma.user.update({
                where: { id: user.id },
                data: { accessToken: accessToken },
            });
            res.status(200).cookie('token', accessToken, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: false,
                sameSite: 'lax',
                expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 1000),
            })
            return {msg:'successfully SIGNUP'};
        }
        catch (error: any) { 
            if (error instanceof PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
                if (error.code === 'P2002') {
                    if (Array.isArray(error.meta?.target)) {
                        if (error.meta.target.includes('email')) {
                            res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already exists' });
                        } else if (error.meta.target.includes('username')) {
                            res.status(400).json({ error: 'Username already exists' });
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
            }
        }
    }

    // @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    async login(@Req() req, @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: ExpressResponse) {
    try {
        const email = req.body.email;
        const user = await this.userService.getUser({ email });
        if (!user) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: 'User not found' });
            return;
        }
        else {
            const accessToken = await this.signToken(user.id, user.email);
            await this.prisma.user.update({
                where: { id: user.id },
                data: { accessToken: accessToken },
            });
            res.cookie("ok", "123");
            console.log({"res login": res});
            res.status(200).cookie('tokenfdp', accessToken, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: false,
                sameSite: 'lax',
                expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 1000),
            })
            return {msg:'Successfully LOGIN', token: accessToken};
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('Login error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        }
    }
```

Any ideas ? I generate them the same way.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the cookie-parser middleware? https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies